# Twig Error: Unknown tag name "stylesheets"

Tags: css, symfony, twig, silex

I'm creating small blog on Silex, using Twig for rendering views. Now I've got an error:

**Unknown tag name "stylesheets" in "index.html" at line 5**

Here is my stylesheet tag:

```
{% stylesheets '../css/main.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

As I understood, we can not use tag, because it's only Symfony2 approach and this tag related to AsseticBundle. So how I can include stylesheets without it?

Comment: Your right, there is no assetic so you just habe to use the standard html way `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
   <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endblock %}
```